# create all possible variations of a string with inserted character

Tags: javascript

I'm trying to take the variable `email` and create all possible combinations with a "." in it like so:

Results

```
andrew
andre.w
andr.ew
andr.e.w
and.rew
and.re.w
and.r.ew
and.r.e.w
an.drew
an.dre.w
an.dr.ew
an.dr.e.w
an.d.rew
an.d.re.w
an.d.r.ew
an.d.r.e.w
a.ndrew
a.ndre.w
a.ndr.ew
a.ndr.e.w
a.nd.rew
a.nd.re.w
a.nd.r.ew
a.nd.r.e.w
a.n.drew
a.n.dre.w
a.n.dr.ew
a.n.dr.e.w
a.n.d.rew
a.n.d.re.w
a.n.d.r.ew
a.n.d.r.e.w
```

I'm not sure how to do about doing this exactly. I know how to use a loop to go over each character, but as far as the rest goes I'm stumped. I was looking at `substr`, `slice` and few other functions but couldn't get anything working.

Code

```
var email = "andrew";

for (var i = 0; i < email.length; i++) {
    console.log( email[i] + "." );
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That's easy:

```
var str = 'andrew';

var results = [],
    bin;

for (var i = 0; i < Math.pow(2, str.length - 1); ++i) {
    bin = i.toString(2).split('').reverse().join('');
    results.push(str.replace(/./g, function(letter, index) {
        if (bin.charAt(index) == 1) {
            letter += '.';
        }
        return letter;
    }));
}

console.log(results);
```

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/9qLY6/

Short description:

For `'abc'` string there are 2 positions for a dot character: between `a` and `b`; `b` and `c`. These 2 positions might be presented as a digits of a binary number. All the possible combinations in this case are:

- `00`
- `01`
- `10`
- `11`

If you treat `1` as - `.` there, and `0` as no `.` there - you can just iterate over `2^(n-1)` numbers and put `.` if the corresponding bit is set.

Answer (score 2):

If you're interested in a recursive solution like Dinesh mentioned, here's some code to get you started.

```
function withPeriods(str, prev) {
    prev = prev || '';
    if(!str || str.length == 0) {
        return prev ? [prev] : [];
    } else if(str.length == 1) {
        return [prev + str];
    } else {
        var c = str.charAt(0);
        var newStr = str.slice(1);
        return withPeriods(newStr, prev+c).concat(withPeriods(newStr, prev+c+'.'));
    }
}
```

The idea here is that you are working your way through the string, keeping the current result in the 'prev' variable. If the string is length 0 or 1, there's nothing left to do. Otherwise, you need consider two options: one where you take a character from 'str' and add it to 'prev', and one where you do that but also add a '.'

Comment: And probably a bit more clear recursive solution that follows the divide an conquer principles: http://jsfiddle.net/epMs2/1/

Comment: That's certainly more succinct, but I don't think it's more clear.

Comment: indeed. Probably more clear for people who prefer functional style over imperative.

Answer (score 1):

If you think about it, you need to either insert a dot, or not insert one, at every possible location in the string (between any two characters). A funky way to do this is to realize that if you have n characters, there are `n-1` places. If you wrote the combinations of `period = 1` and `no period = 0`, then you can write all possible solutions as a 2^n-1 binary sequence.  Showing this for a four letter word "word":

```
000    word
001    wor.d
010    wo.rd
011    wo.r.d
100    w.ord
101    w.or.d
110    w.o.rd
111    w.o.r.d
```

In pseudo code (can't test JS syntax right now):

```
n = strlen( email );
combinations = 1 << n - 1;  // left shift operation
for i = 0 to combinations - 1:
  dot = 1
  for j = 0 to n:
    print email[j];
    if dot & i:
      print '.'
    dot << 1;
```

Can you take it from here?

Answer (score 0):

You might take a recursive approach to this problem. Maybe you can use the base case as a string with 2 characters.